# Triple Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Use cylindrical coordinates to evaluate the triple integral $$\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\, dV,$$ where $\mathrm{E}$ is the solid bounded by the circular paraboloid $z=1-9(x^{2}+y^{2})$ and the $xy$-plane.

I tried really hard to get the limits but i couldn't get them

Comment: You can use cylinderical coordinates.

Comment: Yeah it says that in the question, but the thing is that i'm not getting a right thing!

Comment: Your region in the $xy$- plane is the circle with radius $1/3$.

Comment: Well, now I am even more confused, can you please explain to me how did you get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$, the integrand is $r$. The paraboloid is $z = 1- 9r^2$. It cuts the $xy$-plane where $z = 0$, i.e., where $1 = 9r^2 \Rightarrow r = {1\over 3}$. For the volume element, you could use annular shapes with volume $dV = 2\pi r \, dr\,dz$. So we have
$$\int_{r=0}^{1/3}{\int_{z=0}^{1-9r^2}{r\cdot 2\pi r\,dr\,dz}} = {4\pi\over 405}$$

Comment: thanks man that was really helpful!

Comment: @user131040 glad to help - just make sure it's right :-)